# How to use INDEX() inside ARRAYFORMULA()?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use the `INDEX()` formula inside an `ARRAYFORMULA()`. As a simple (non-sense) example, with 4 elements in column `A`, I expected that the following array formula entered in `B1` would display all four elements from `A` in column `B`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,ROW($A$1:$A$4)))
```

However, this only fills field `B1` with a the value found in `A1`.

When I enter

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW($A$1:$A$4))
```

in `B1`, then I do see all numbers 1 to 4 appear in column `B`. Why does my first array formula not expand similar like the second one does?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The INDEX function is one that does not support "iteration" over an array if an array is used as one of its arguments. There is no documentation of this that I know of; it simply is what it is. So the second argument will always default to the first element of the array, which is ROW(A1).

One clumsy workaround to achieve what you require relies on a second adjacent column existing next to the source data* (although it is unimportant what values are actually in that second column):

`=ArrayFormula(HLOOKUP(IF(ROW($A$1:$A$4);$A$1);$A$1:$B$4;ROW($A$1:$A$4);0))`

or indeed something like:

`=ArrayFormula(HLOOKUP(IF({3;2;4;1};$A$1);$A$1:$B$4;{3;2;4;1};0))`

---

*edit 2015-06-09*

* This is no longer a requirement in the newest version of Sheets; the second argument in the HLOOKUP can just be $A$1:$A$4.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a tip for using `vlookup` with an array, so that even if the columns are moved later on the formula will still work correctly....

In general, configure the vlookup so that it's reading only 2 columns and returning the second. This can be done by inputting only the 2 columns required, rather than a range and column index.

Example:

Replace the following formula which would fail if columns are moved

```
=arrayformula( vlookup(C:C, booking!$A:$E ,5 ,false) )
```

with this formula which will continue to work even if columns are moved

```
=arrayformula( vlookup(C:C, {booking!$A:$A,booking!$E:$E} ,2 ,false) )
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Your `{booking!$A:$A,booking!$E:$E}` saved me

Answer (score 0):

Note, you can also simulate the index function using vlookup.

Example:

Column R:R contains the row index numbers for looking up data in column booking!$A:$A

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(R:R ,arrayformula({row(booking!$A:$A), booking!$A:$A}),2 , false))
```

It's a nested array, so it can be helpful to test in stages, eg just the inner part for one example, eg return entry in row 10:

```
=vlookup(10 ,arrayformula({row(booking!$A:$A), booking!$A:$A}),2 , false)
```