# Google Sheets ArrayFormula that returns an index of the column that matched specified criteria for each row

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I've been searching for several hours for what I thought would be a pretty straight forward problem but without any luck.

I need an array formula (needs to calculate for range without copying down the formula) that returns an index reference to the column containing a match for the passed criteria for each row. I don't need the value returned, which is what I've seen related problems solving for, just the column index. I will be using the returned index value to pull data from a bound matrix containing data such as allocated hours. I tried to use MATCH inside an ArrayFormula with a dynamic index for the lookup range but it doesn't increment the row as I would expect. Below is example data with the desired results shown in the first column (technically the results will be returned in a separate worksheet but included here for illustrative purposes), assignee is the criteria for which to find the matching column index across reviewers 1 - 3.

```html
   
   +---------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
   | Results | Assignee | Reviewer 1 | Reviewer 2 | Reviewer 3 |
   +---------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
   |       2 | Paul     | Tim        | Paul       | Sue        |
   |       1 | Nick     | Nick       | Linda      | Adam       |
   |       3 | Bill     | Ryan       | Paul       | Bill       |
   |       2 | Tom      | Paul       | Tom        | Sarah      |
   +---------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I've been struggling with this for a while so any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't get why "`=MATCH(B2,C2:E2,0)`" shouldn't work? It will return the position of the Reviewer, which would correspond to the column 1-3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140642/how-to-use-index-inside-arrayformula

Comment: I have an answer for this, but it is more convoluted than i think it would be to return the actual data from the bound matrix sch as allocated hours.  That is, i think the solution to the NEXT step is simpler than this intermediary step.  Tough to tell without a sample sheet.  Share an editable sheet to demo the problem (including the "next step") and i think i can help

Comment: @Wizhi the MATCH formula does not work within an arrayformula as the range can only be a single row or column. It does not iterate through "C2:E2" like you would expect from an ArrayFormula

Comment: @ MattKing linked is a workbook with example data tables https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16hNEG0mHR7D0Rtgpw5DGZUKPvnnVZmzRMJebyCufm3o/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=MMULT(ARRAYFORMULA(--('Table 2'!A3:D7) * --('Table 1'!A3:A7 = 'Table 1'!B3:E7)), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS('Table 1'!B3:E7), 1, 1, 0))
```

1. `--('Table 2'!A3:D7)` - places `0`s instead of blanks in table 2 (needed for `MMULT`).
2. `--('Table 1'!A3:A7 = 'Table 1'!B3:E7)` - gives a table with `1`s in cells corresponding to current reviewer, and `0`s in all the other.
3. Then those two ranges are multiplied cell by cell. That gives a table with the right hours in cells with the reviewers' names, one value in a row.
4. `MMULT` gives a row wise sum, which is effectively a column of those hours from the previous step.

[image]

If you'll have a bigger table you'll just need to adjust `Table 1'!A3:A7`, `'Table 1'!B3:E7`, and `Table 2'!A3:D7` accordingly. The rest will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

The best I've been able to come up with so far is this SWITCH statement. It works but not so elegant

```
=ArrayFormula(SWITCH(Current_Assignee, INDEX(Queue,,1), "1", INDEX(Queue,,2), "2", INDEX(Queue,,3), "3", INDEX(Queue,,4), "4", INDEX(Queue,,5), "5"))
```