# How do I return the value corresponding to an index selection in an array?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, flatten, google-query-language

I've got form users from different companies making a selection from 1 to 10 and I need to get the corresponding value in an array unique to each user's company.

Effectively, I think this needs the equivalent of INDEX() in an ARRAYFORMULA(), so I've had a look at the answers to similar questions:

> [How to use INDEX() inside ARRAYFORMULA()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140642/how-to-use-index-inside-arrayformula)

> [What is an equivalent for INDEX in ARRAYFORMULA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527113/what-is-an-equivalent-for-index-in-arrayformula)

While these look similar, I can't figure out how to apply the proposed formulas to my challenge - I've tried applying them but get errors I don't understand how to fix.

I've created a [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PvAVkGmPb3myJUyfB6I5uATPx1u37s8M9s7e_1ApKBs/edit?usp=sharing) to demonstrate the desired results:

- Responses sheet has the form responses
- Reference sheet has the reference values
- Results sheet has the desired result (corresponding value returned based on the index number selected by the user)

Comment: @player0 can you help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A&"×"&B2:B, TRIM(SPLIT(QUERY(IFERROR(FLATTEN(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(Reference!A2:A, 
 TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({Responses!A2:A, Responses!B2:B&"×", Responses!A2:A&"¤"}, 
 "select Col2,max(Col3) where Col1 <>'×' group by Col2 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", )),,9^9)), "×")), 2, ), "¤")&"×"&
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({Reference!A2:A, "¤"&Reference!B2:K}),,9^9)))), 
 "where not Col1 starts with '×' and Col1 is not null", ), "¤")), 
 VLOOKUP(A2:A&"×"&B2:B, {Responses!A2:A&"×"&Responses!B2:B, Responses!C2:C+1}, 2, ), )))
```

[image]